# SQL query that looks at multiple rows for a column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to craft a query that selects rows based off a repeat value in a column

```
Row 1:             Row 2:            Row 3:           Row 4:
Record_Key = 1     Record_Key = 1    Record_Key = 2   Record_Key = 3
Type = 'AED'       Type = 'ACD'      Type = 'AED'     Type = 'AED'
```

I only want to select rows that have a `Record_Key` of `AED` that don't have an `ACD` associated with that `Record_Key`.

So in my provided example, I only want to select `Row 3` and `Row 4`.

I can't say:

```
Select * From Table Where Type != 'ACD'
```

because this would return `Row 1`, `Row 3`, and `Row 4` when I only want `Row 3` and `Row 4`. I can't wrap my head around structuring this query, or does SQL and my provided table not allow for this kind of select?

Comment: WHERE Type='AED' AND NOT EXISTS(...)    This question has been asked and answered many times, but it is a difficult scenario to search for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use not exists

```
    select t1.* from tab t1
    where not exists ( select 1 from tab t2 where t1.Record_Key=t2.Record_Key
                                       and type='ACD')
```

output

```
Record_Key  Type
2           AED
3          AED
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f306ae63652885c418dfcd8cba99d89d)

Comment: There is only 1 table

Comment: @Josh yes i used only one table

Comment: @Josh https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f306ae63652885c418dfcd8cba99d89d  check this link for your output

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.type = 'AED' and 
      not exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.record_key = t.record_key and t1.type = 'ACD');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `group by record_key` and keep only `record_key`s where the only existing `type` is `'AED'`:

```
select record_key, max(type) type 
from tab
where type in ('AED', 'ACD') 
group by record_key
having min(type) = 'AED' and max(type) = 'AED'
```